# Animate a Rotation in Beamer animateinline

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations, animate

I wanted to animate some steam engine and got some trouble. I reduced the problem and realised a fundamental problem.

When I try to rotate a simple square with animateinline, the square gets scaled. (more complicated objects even get sheared)

Can anyone help please?
THX

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}


\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{25}
\multiframe{50}{iAngle=0+1}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rotate=\iAngle] (0,0)rectangle++(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like animateinline needs some bounding boxes.

[see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509409/animateinline-problems?rq=1)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}


\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{25}
\multiframe{50}{iAngle=0+1}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-4,-4) rectangle ++(13,10);
\draw[rotate=\iAngle] (0,0)rectangle++(2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}


\end {document}
```